# pyqt4 reference for python?

Tags: python, reference, pyqt4

Most of the reference site i visited are for C/C++. Is there a reference site of pyqt4 for python? Like https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/classes.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely! I use the [classes](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html) page in their [reference guide](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/index.html). Happy coding! :)

Comment: A similar documentation that looks nicer, has more information, and should be compatible, is available for [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/) as well.

Answer (score 4):

I feel comfortable using the help() function through the Python interactive interpreter.

$python

> > > from PyQt4 import QtGui
> > >
> > > help(QtGui)
> > >
> > > help(QtGui.QTextEdit)